# Passing parameter to typescript decorators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

So, I am working on developing a CRUD server in nestjs, using Mongo as the database, and I am trying to inject the database connection that can be obtained from the service constructor (`@InjectConnection() private connection?: mongoose.Connection`), into a decorator by doing `@Decorator(this.connection)`. This is not possible because the decorator factory runs before the connection to the database has been initialised. With this being, every time that the decorator is used, the connection is undefined. Is there a workaround for this kind of situation? I really wan't to implement the solution using typescript decorators.

Answer (score 0):

decorators in typescript has 3 arguments. target which is the prototype of the class, key which is the key that you are applying the decorator to and third descriptors which is to change the value of the key. essentially when you type @Decorator, typescripts sees it as a function. this is how you defined your decorator.

```
@Decorator=function Decorator(target:any,key:string,desc:PropertyDescriptor){}
```

now you want to write it like this

```
@Decorator()
```

that means you have add additional () to the right side as well. this is simple maths.

```
  @Decorator()=function Decorator()(target:any,key:string,desc:PropertyDescriptor){}
```

what you have to do is you have define decorator as the function which returns a function with those parameters.

```
function Decorator(...args){
   return function(target:any,key:string,desc:PropertyDescriptor){
   // you can access to ...args here
 }}
```